# Xcode/IB multiple container views pointing at single view controller?

Tags: xcode, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder, containers

In the interface builder you can drag out an "Container View" which links up to an different view controller. I've used this functionality several times, works great.

Is it possible for several of these container views to point to the same view controller *in IB*? Think of it as several view controllers who all want to contain the same re-usable view controller. I've been messing around for it for a good hour and can't find out how to do it (in IB), so I'm guessing it's not possible. I just wanted to make sure I didn't miss it because it would be really useful.

PS. Please don't bother explaining how to accomplish this in code. I've done it and can easily do it in code. It would just be nice to manage this in a storyboard with all the connections setup visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't do this in IB. Only in code. (even a year later)

For those of you who might be trying to do it, the easiest way is to create the container view controller in IB with the containment view pointing no where. Create the contained view controller, also in IB. Then write the code to add the child view controller when needed.